# Php to auto populate grids

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="media row-fluid">

                    <div class="span3">
                        <div class="widget">
                            <div class="well">
                                <div class="view">
                                    <a href="img/demo/big.jpg" class="view-back lightbox"></a>
                                    <img src="img/demo/media/1.png" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info">
                                    <a href="#" title="" class="item-title">Title 1</a>
                                    <p>Info.</p>
                                    <p class="item-buttons">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info tip" title="Edit"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger tip" title="Move to trash"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="widget">
                            <div class="well">
                                <div class="view">
                                    <a href="img/demo/big.jpg" class="view-back lightbox"></a>
                                    <img src="img/demo/media/2.png" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info">
                                    <a href="#" title="" class="item-title">This is another title</a>
                                    <p>Some info and details go here.</p>
                                    <p class="item-buttons">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info tip" title="Edit"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger tip" title="Move to trash"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Which basically alternates between a span class with the widget class, and then the widget class without the span3 class.

What I wanted to know was if there was a way to have php "echo" or populate the details for   and details under the "item-info" class. Would I need to use a foreach statement to get this done? I would be storing the information in a mysql database, and while I can get it to fill in the info one by one (repeatedly entering the  and echoing out each image and item title) it's not practical when the content needed to be displayed is over 15 different items. I'm not well versed in foreach statements so I could definitely use some help on it.

If someone could help me perhaps structure a php script so that it can automatically output the html based on the number individual items in the database, that'd be greatly appreciated!

I'm wondering if the html + php (not including the foreach) would look like this:

```
<div class="span3">
                        <div class="widget">
                            <div class="well">
                                <div class="view">
                                    <a href="<? $link ?>" class="view-back lightbox"></a>
                                    <img src="img/<? $file ?>" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info">
                                    <a href="#" title="" class="item-title"><?$title?></a>
                                    <p>Info.</p>
                                    <p class="item-buttons">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info tip" title="Edit"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger tip" title="Move to trash"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

---

EDIT:

I wanted to add some more information. The items populated would be based on a type of subscription - which will be managed by a group id.

I was initially going to use `<? (if $_SESSION['group_id']==1)>`

```
echo <div class="item-info">
                                    <a href="#" title="" class="item-title">$title</a>
                                    <p>$info</p>

                                </div>
```

so that only the subscribed items would populate. But, I would need it to iterate through all the items for group1 table and list it. Currently I know that I can do

```
<? (if $_SESSION['group_id']==1)
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlItem))
{ 
 $itemInfo = $row['info'];
 $image = $row['image'];
 $title = $row['title'];
 $url = $row['url'];
};
>
```

`$sqlItem` for now can only be assigned one thing (manually - as in: $sqlItem = '123'), unless I iterate through which is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: What php code have you already written?

Comment: You mean "How do I iterate over an array and produce a list of items"?

Comment: @tadman I guess, if that's what it's called. Sorry I'm new to this - so I'm not entirely sure what it would be termed as

Comment: @DiMono as far as the foreach goes nothing. I'm not even sure how to start it. I know that the function is foreach($x = 0; $x < count($somevar); $x++) but I don't know what to pass in to $somevar from the sql database or how to get whatever is in that foreach to produce a list of items.

Comment: No, that's a `for()` loop. `foreach()` is how you iterate through an array that already exists. `foreach($array as $key => $value)`. Then if `$value` happens to be an array as well, you access it like any other array.

Comment: @Fahad No problem, I was just trying to boil down what you were asking to something more concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read that 'mysql_fetch_assoc' is being depreciated with 5.5, here is the new way and looks better, easier I think..  Hope this helps, was updated today.
I hope this helps http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php
replace the printf with echo '//then your html stuff

This will iterate through the rows in your database until their are no more matching records.

Comment: great, thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for. And it's pretty easy lol. The user example shows how to pass it into an array which is perfect. I'll try this out shortly

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't a `while` be enough? It depends on the structure of your database and website (we didn't need so much HTML I think. Some more PHP maybe). Hope this helps.

Comment: Added what I'm currently using as a while statement in the question. I just don't know how to iterate through multiple rows, and output that information and thought a foreach would be better.